# Setting maximum and minimum size in an Electron BrowserWindow

Tags: javascript, electron

Whenever I set the maximum size of the BrowserWindow, it resets the minimum size. Likewise, whenever I set the minimum size, it resets the maximum size. I need both a maximum and minimum size for my BrowserWindow. Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to set both the maximum and minimum sizes of a BrowserWindow?

```
mainWindow.setMinimumSize(minimumSize.width, minimumSize.height);
mainWindow.setMaximumSize(maximumSize.width, maximumSize.height);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a an [active issue at the Electron Github repository](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6122) concerning this problem that is being investigated.

The current workaround seems to require a little time between both calls:

```
setTimeout(() => remote.getCurrentWindow().setMaximumSize(300, 300), 200);
remote.getCurrentWindow().setMinimumSize(50, 50);
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I added more information to the active issue, though. Guess there's no real point to have this question open any more.

Comment: The issue seems to have been resolved only a couple of days after our discussion, it has been integrated starting with Electron 1.2.7.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for informing me.

Comment: for some reason when i use `setMinimumSize`, it seems as if `usecContentSize` to `false`. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This question and its answers are from mid-2016, a fix for the workaround mentioned in this answer has been merged within a week of its discovery. Electron has had plenty of releases since then, even if related, I am pretty sure that your question should be posted as a new question instead of a comment on this answer.